# One .sol File And Multiple Contracts With Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-invocation

I have the following sol file "Token.sol"

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract Token {

/// @return total amount of tokens
function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply) {}

/// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
/// @return The balance
function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {}

/// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
/// @param _to The address of the recipient
/// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
/// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

/// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
/// @param _from The address of the sender
/// @param _to The address of the recipient
/// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
/// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

/// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_addr` to spend `_value` tokens
/// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
/// @param _value The amount of wei to be approved for transfer
/// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

/// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
/// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
/// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {}

event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);}
contract StandardToken is Token {

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    //Default assumes totalSupply can't be over max (2^256 - 1).
    //If your token leaves out totalSupply and can issue more tokens as time goes on, you need to check if it doesn't wrap.
    //Replace the if with this one instead.
    //if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    //same as above. Replace this line with the following if you want to protect against wrapping uints.
    //if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
    if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
  return allowed[_owner][_spender];
}

mapping (address => uint256) balances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
uint256 public totalSupply;}

contract HumanStandardToken is StandardToken {

function () {
    //if ether is sent to this address, send it back.
    throw;
}

/* Public variables of the token */

/*
NOTE:
The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
*/
string public name;                   //fancy name: eg Simon Bucks
uint8 public decimals;                //How many decimals to show. ie. There could 1000 base units with 3 decimals. Meaning 0.980 SBX = 980 base units. It's like comparing 1 wei to 1 ether.
string public symbol;                 //An identifier: eg SBX
string public version = 'H0.1';       //human 0.1 standard. Just an arbitrary versioning scheme.

function HumanStandardToken(
    uint256 _initialAmount,
    string _tokenName,
    uint8 _decimalUnits,
    string _tokenSymbol
    ) {
    balances[msg.sender] = _initialAmount;               // Give the creator all initial tokens
    totalSupply = _initialAmount;                        // Update total supply
    name = _tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    decimals = _decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    symbol = _tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
}

/* Approves and then calls the receiving contract */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

    //call the receiveApproval function on the contract you want to be notified. This crafts the function signature manually so one doesn't have to include a contract in here just for this.
    //receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _tokenContract, bytes _extraData)
    //it is assumed that when does this that the call *should* succeed, otherwise one would use vanilla approve instead.
    if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { throw; }
    return true;
}}
```

which truffle splits into 3 .sol files. The contract  HumanStandardToken has an initializer function but can't figure out how to trigger the code in the deploy_contracts.js file.

I'm doing the following

```
var Coin = artifacts.require("Token")

module.exports = function(deployer) {
deployer.deploy(Coin, '800000000000000000000000000', 'CoinName', 18, 
'MDC',{gas: 4700000})
};
```

But the test do not pass when I check for totalSupply().

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "../contracts/Token.sol";


contract TestToken {

  function testTotalSupplyOfCoin() {
    Token meta = new Token();

    uint expected = 8000000000000;

    Assert.equal(meta.totalSupply(), expected, "Owner should have 8000000000000 Coins initially");
  }

}
```

> Error: Owner should have 8000000000000 MetaCoin initially (Tested: 0, Against: 8000000000000)

Edit: I have to add that
when I use the console it works as expected

```
Web3 = require('web3')
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
code = fs.readFileSync('contracts/Token.sol').toString()
contract =  web3.eth.compile.solidity(code)
CoinContract = web3.eth.contract(contract.info.abiDefinition)
deployedContract = CoinContract.new('800000000000000000000000000', 'CoinName', 18, 'MDC',{data: contract.code, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000})})
contractInstance = CoinContract.at(deployedContract.address)
contractInstance.totalSupply()
{ [String: '8e+26'] s: 1, e: 26, c: [ 8000000000000 ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the deploy script as follows

```
var HumanStandardToken = artifacts.require("HumanStandardToken")

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(HumanStandardToken, '800000000000000000000000000', 'CoinName', 18, 
    'MDC',{gas: 4700000})
};
```

This way you're deploying the `HumanStandardToken` rather than the abstract base class.

Comment: I went to bed thinking the same thing, I just tried it but still no luck.